# Checking number positions in bankaccount

Tags: java

So I have the following problem of a task that I need to make. It's about checking if a bankaccount number is correct or not this is the task:

The first group consists of 3 digits and determines which bank it is .
The second group consists of 7 digits and establishes the customer goes to that bank.
The third group consists of two numbers and a check digit which the validity of the bank account is determined .

The verification is done as follows:
The first and second group together form a number consisting of 10 digits. If you divide this number by 97 then the remainder after division by 97 must be equal to the third group of the bankaccount.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Sounds cool. What did you try to solve it?

Comment: More clarification please .. show your issue?

Comment: Is this a kind of homework? Or do you think that StackOverflow is a magical code writing site?

Comment: So the third group consists of two or three digits?

Comment: @JeanPaul : out of curiosity, did you accepted answer because it was *what you were looking for* or because question was put on hold?

Comment: @NoobEditor I found the solution the accepter answer was definitly a helpful tool. It was not what i was looking for but it got me started to find the rest of the code myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
private boolean checkNumber(String number) {
        //number consists of 12 digits
        String firstGroup = number.substring(0, 3);
        String secondGroup = number.substring(3, 10);
        String thirdGroup = number.substring(10, 12);

        int firstSecond = Integer.parseInt(firstGroup + secondGroup);
        int third = Integer.parseInt(thirdGroup);

        int remainderAfterDevision = firstSecond % 97;

        return (remainderAfterDevision == third);
}
```